# Product is not added to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with adding a product on the website to cart. This website was not developed by me, so at first I looked through the code and found a "button" which calls popup for a quick order, here it is (wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/single-product/price.php):

```
<a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart eModal-1" data-product="<?=$product->id;?>" onclick="yaCounter33486453.reachGoal('oneclick'); return true;"><? echo __('submit your application', 'lati')?></a>
```

I have changed it to:

```
<a href="http://example.com/?add-to-cart=<?=$product->id;?>" class="btn add-to-cart" data-product="<?=$product->id;?>"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></a>
```

So when I click on this button it just redirects to the main page and nothing happens. I have tried to redirect to /cart/?add-to-cart=id;?> but still nothing, it says that the cart is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

1. So I looked again and found the following code in single products page:

> ```
> <form class="cart" method="post" ... style="display: none;">
> ...
> <input name="add-to-cart" value="..." type="hidden">
> <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
> </form>
> ```

Why is it automatically hidden?

2. Also the $_SESSION['order'] has the value NULL.

Comment: where you are doing the changes? I mean inside any custom template that you have made or inside plugin?

Comment: @NewUser Inside my custom template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cart template was wrong. Previous programmers added their own template, but I changed it to the basic one and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Woocommerce is a plugin that is supposed to be edited the "Editor" and nothing else. I would not recommend using it and i would not recommend using Wordpress for a store.

Ive been there, done that and will not recommend it...

Answer:

Replace your echo with the following, this should echo it out on the page:
 `echo ('submit your application')`

And then style it in your CSS Document

Comment: The problem is not in button title, it is in add-to-cart function.

Comment: Ohhh ok, Button functions like the one WooCommerce use cannot be changed directly in the code with redoing alot of their code... I will recommend keeping the button as it is but adding a statement that makes a "Header" after like this:

header("Location: mypage.com/Index.php");